# is there anyway to add a primary autonumber key to an already existing database table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

i have inherited a database application from someone else and there are a few tables that dont have any primary keys.  I want to add a new column into an already existing table and have it autonumber (starting from 1).  how would i go about doing this?

Comment: what is your purpose for doing this work?

Comment: i need to delete a number of rows and the only way i can do it now is by using the timestamp field.  It would be much easier if i could say "delete from tableA where id = 100"

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a ROWID column?

Comment: @Stephanie Page - i dont follow your point

Comment: You're adding a column to a database in order to DELETE t WHERE id = 100. You could just as easily DELETE t WHERE rowid = AaaAAbAb without adding a column, forcing a trigger to fire, wasting storage space.

Comment: @Stephanie Page, no SQL Server does not have a rowid column like Oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL Server syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable PRIMARY KEY [NON]CLUSTERED (ID)
```